JSON Code is having no Effect on Column Formatting in a SharePoint Online List
In SharePoint Online, I have permissions as "Owner" (not ADMIN). I have created a list. The column types vary (of type URL, Text, Date, etc.).
For the URL column, I added the following JSON code to ensure the URL field does not extend too wide, but this does absolutely nothing:
{
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column- 
   formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "width": "200px"
      }
    }

Now, I added code to one of the text columns that contains a list of dropdown choices because I want the cell to be highlighted, depending on what was selected, and still no change shows up in the list.
{
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column- 
       formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "background-color": "=if(@currentField == 'New', '#89CFF0', if(@currentField 
    == 'Resolved',  '#A9F5BC', if(@currentField == 'Under Review', '#FFFFFF', 
    if(@currentField == 'Need More Information', '#F5DA81', if(@currentField == 
    'More Information Added', '#F5DA81', if(@currentField == 'Waiting', '#F79F81', 
    if(@currentField == 'Returned', '#FA5858', '#89CFF0')))))))"
      },
     "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
      "display": "inline-block",
      "padding": "0 4px"
    },
     "attributes": {
         "iconName": "=if(@currentField == 'New', 'Star', if(@currentField == 
    'Resolved', 'CheckMark', if(@currentField == 'Under Review', 'Forward', 
    if(@currentField == 'Need More Information', 'Error', if(@currentField == 'More 
    Information Added', 'Error', if(@currentField == 'Waiting', 'Warning', 
    if(@currentField == 'Returned', 'ErrorBadge', 'CheckMark')))))))"
    }
    },
      {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
    ]
    }

It is behaving like any JSON code I add for any column is being totally ignored (does nothing). When I return to the Column format for that column to see the code, it is still there (but does nothing).
Do I have to be an ADMIN to add the JSON code? Is there something else that I am missing? Is there some setting that does not allow/permit the execution of JSON code?
A few weeks ago, I did a simple test and change the color of the text in a column, and that worked. I removed that code and replace it with the code above to control the width of the column, and the column still shows as green text. So weird.

You don't need admin permissions to apply JSON column formatting (Full control permissions on list are enough). Are you using list in modern experience? Can you attach screenshot of list and where you are applying the JSON?

Please try to create a new list and use the above JSON to see if the results are the same.
